# Image showing only in debug

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a strange situation

I load an external image in my desktop application.

```
BitmapImage cover = new BitmapImage(new Uri("cover.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
MyImage.Source = cover;
```

Where MyImage is the WPF Image Control

When i run my application, there is no image.
If i debug my application the image is there

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: the application is always run in debug. If i set no breakpoint and the application go through, the image doesn't appear. if i put a breakpoint on that line, the image appear. i have no release folder yet

Comment: @PietroCarta: When you debug, are you inspecting any values in a way that might cause side-effects? For example, are you calling a method in a "watch" that might cause the image to be created?

Comment: i inspect the cover. base

Comment: I got curious: If you try MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); Does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you don't want to use a relative Uri.  If the file is not in your project and you are assuming that it's in the local folder, you would do the following:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("cover.jpg");
MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: Bumped into the same problem and solved with your answer, thx. But why??? It makes no sense

Comment: I have no idea what's going wrong there, but the issue seems to persist, still. With this answer you just ended a five-hours long troubleshooting for race condition, i/o issues and render time problems. Wouldn't have expected the root of issues to be THERE. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The image probably is Located in the bin\Debug folder, but not in the bin\Release folder.

Comment: the application is always run in debug. If i set no breakpoint and the application go through, the image doesn't appear. if i put a breakpoint on that line, the image appear. i have no release folder yet